# Xcode 6.1 iPad Retina simulator slowdown?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I created a Universal device app game. The retina iPad app game was created in Xcode 5.1.1. When I tested on the full screen iPad Retina simulator game worked perfectly. I installed Xcode 6.1 to work on iPhone 6,6+. I don't understand why full screen simulator iPad Retina made game work well on Xcode 5.1.1 and now same iPad Retina simulator slows down on full screen on Xcode 6.1. I had the exact same code in Xcode 5.1.1 iPad Retina storyboards as in Xcode 6.1's iPad Retina storyboards so i don't know what to change in code to stop the slow down. Can it be that iPad Retina simulator full screen doesn't work well and makes game lag in Xcode 6.1 even though game worked perfectly in iPad Retina simulator in Xcode 5.1.1 with full screen simulator?

(I ask because I found bugs with Xcode 6.1 besides my slow down issue)

Comment: There are and have been a lot of bugs in Xcode. To answer your question: of course that is possible. But that strongly depends on your hardware. (So it is not an actual bug) You always have to test on real devices to see the actual performance.

Comment: It's not the same simulator. You have updated Xcode and therefore you have updated the simulator. Test on real device.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Can it be that iPad Retina simulator full screen doesn't work well and makes game lag in Xcode 6.1'?  The iOS Simulator does not have a full-screen mode.  Is your game full-screen *within* the iOS Simulator?

Comment: If you open the iPad Retina simulators the smallest scale is 50% But that loads a huge screen with a scroller. I'm using a macBook Pro and the simulator loads from the top of my screen to the bottom. It's pretty huge. I call that full-screen mode.

Comment: You should not call that fullscreen mode.  The term fullscreen means something different.  The window size and scale have no impact on tuntime performance.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Xcode is not as important as the version of iOS you are testing with.  As you haven't specified that, I suspect you are testing with iOS 7.1 with Xcode 5.1 and with iOS 8.1 with Xcode 6.1.

Try installing the iOS 7.1 simulator from Xcode 6.1's Preferences -> Downloads and running your app in iOS 7.1.  You should see the exact same behavior as you did in the past.

From there, I would focus on determining what the differences are between iOS 7.1 and 8.1 that are impacting your app.

Note that the iOS Simulator is not designed to be a good measure of performance of your app on a real device.  Many things perform much better in the sim than on device, and other things perform significantly worse (like SpriteKit, OpenGL).

Comment: Fox Xcode 5.1.1 i only had iOS 7.1 simulator. For Xcode 6.1 i have iOS 7.1 and 8.1 simulator. In Xcode 6.1, doesn't matter if it's iOS 7.1 or 8.1, the iPad Retina simulator slows down the gameplay at some points. The iPad non-retina simulators iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.1 that doesn't load full screen, also has the exact same code, doesn't have any issue at all. Not using SpriteKit.

Comment: Well there are signifigantly more (4x) pixels in the retina sim.  Have you profiled your app to see where you are spending your time?  I guarantee that iOS 7.1 Simulator is exactly (bit for bit) the same in as it was in Xcode 5.1.1